# git rebase a branch since it was created

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

At the moment when rebasing a branch (e.g. a *feature branch* before merging into *master*) I have to manually look up when the branch was created to tell `git rebase` the start-point for `rebase`.

I have the strong feeling that this can be automated — is there a way to tell `git rebase` to start when the *branch* was created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are working on the branch `feature/foo` which is based on the `master` branch.

```
        F--J--K--|feature/baz|
       /
A--B--D--G--|master|
    \
     C--E--H--|feature/foo|HEAD|
```

In order to `rebase` the work onto `master` there are different options:

1. As [explained by remram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686540/356895) you can explicitly name the target commit using the `--onto`:

   ```
   // 1.1. Will move the flag `feature/foo`
   git rebase --onto master B feature/foo
   // 1.2. Will not move the flag `feature/foo`
   git rebase --onto master B H
   // 1.3. If the HEAD is at H
   git rebase --onto master B
   ```

   Since the `--onto` lets you define the target commit it is useful if you want to rebase `feature/foo` onto `feature/baz` which do not share a common branch base.

   ```
   // 1.4. Will rebase `feature/foo` onto `feature/baz`
   git rebase --onto feature/baz B feature/foo

               /--|feature/baz|
              /
       F--J--K--C'--E'--H'--|feature/foo|HEAD|
      /
   A--B--D--G--|master|
   ```
2. As [explained by Stefan Fleiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686332/356895) you do not have to name the ancestor if `feature/foo` is based on `master`:

   ```
   // 2.1. Explicitly naming feature/foo as the branch to be rebased onto master
   git rebase master feature/foo
   // 2.2. Assuming that feature/foo is currently checked out aka. HEAD
   git checkout feature/foo
   git rebase master
   ```
3. If you do not feel comfortable with the `rebase` process since your former branch `feature/foo` "disappears" `cherry-pick` might be a feel-good alternative for you. The command allows to specify a range of commits and behaves very similar to `rebase --onto`. The difference is that the branch you are cherry-picking from will remain untouched.

   ```
   // 3.1.1. Start by creating a new branch where master is
   git checkout master
   git checkout -b feature/foo-cherried

           F--J--K--|feature/baz|
          /
   A--B--D--G
       \     \
        \     \-|master|feature/foo-cherried|HEAD|
         \
          C--E--H--|feature/foo|


   // 3.1.2. Pick a range starting at the common branch base
   git cherry-pick B..H

           F--J--K--|feature/baz|
          /
   A--B--D--G--C'--E'--H'--|feature/foo-cherried|HEAD|
       \     \
        \     \-|master|
         \
          C--E--H--|feature/foo|


   // 3.1.3. Later on if everything worked fine you can 
   // delete the unmerged branch feature/foo
   git branch -D feature/foo

           F--J--K--|feature/baz|
          /
   A--B--D--G--C'--E'--H'--|feature/foo-cherried|HEAD|
             \
              \-|master|
   ```

For more information about `git rebase --onto` I recommend a blog post here:

- [Git: How to copy a range of commits from one branch to another?](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120928/git-how-to-copy-a-range-of-commits-from-one-branch-to-another/)

Answer (score 2):

What worked very well for me was to just `git rebase master -i`.

This assumes you're 1) standing on the branch you want to rebase and 2) rebase onto master. It will also allow me to edit each committ if neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

The full [rebase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) syntax is `git rebase --onto target starting-point mybranch`. If `mybranch` is omitted, the current one will be used.

In most cases, you can just do `git rebase target`. In this case, the last common ancestor of the current branch (`mybranch`) and `target` will be used (see [merge-base](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html)). So, if you're rebasing a feature branch on the branch it was based on, this last form should work.

See also the [page on rebase from the Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Answer (score 0):

When rebasing a feature branch with git you do not have to know the common ancestor.
Simply switch to your feature branch

```
    git checkout my-feature-branch
```

rebase to master or some other branch you like

```
    git rebase master
```

switch back to master

```
    git checkout master
```

and (fast-forward) merge the feature branch to set HEAD in the master branch to the latest rebased commit.

```
    git merge my-feature-branch
```

For more details please have a look at the [detailed explanation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Basic-Rebase) in the Pro Git book. 
I hope this answers your question.